# Passing dictionary name as a parameter to a lookup function

Tags: python, dictionary

Arrite, python n00b here, please be gentle. ;)

As you can see from the following code, I have a function that stores dictionaries that contain information about different lists that I want to parse and write out to files.  I'm stuck on how to pass the name of the dictionary to the lookup function.  If I pass it as a string, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

So, the question:  How do I pass lookup() the name of the dictionary to look up, e.g., the parameter "URL" and get a result back?

Thanks in advance.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
    
    from re import sub
    from requests import get
    from ipaddress import ip_network
    
    def lookup(listname, key):
        
        spamhaus_drop = {
            "name"            :  "Spamhaus DROP",
            "URL"             :  "https://www.spamhaus.org/drop/drop.txt",
            "filename"        :  "spamhaus_drop.txt",
        }
    
        spamhaus_edrop = {
            "name"            :  "Spamhaus EDROP",
            "URL"             :  "https://www.spamhaus.org/drop/edrop.txt",
            "filename"        :  "spamhaus_edrop.txt",
        }
    
        return listname.get(key)
        
    def getnewlist(listname):
    
        req = get(lookup(listname, 'URL'))           
        newlist = spamhaus_parse(req.text)
        
        return newlist



    def main():
            newlist = getnewlist('spamhaus_drop')
            return(0)
        
   if __name__ == main():
       main()
```

Comment: what's your spamhaus_drop dict doing for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access variables dynamically like that.

Put all your dictionaries in another dictionary, and use `listname` as the key.

```
def lookup(listname, key):
    dicts = {
        'spamhaus_drop': {
            "name"            :  "Spamhaus DROP",
            "URL"             :  "https://www.spamhaus.org/drop/drop.txt",
            "filename"        :  "spamhaus_drop.txt",
            },
        
        'spamhaus_edrop': {
            "name"            :  "Spamhaus EDROP",
            "URL"             :  "https://www.spamhaus.org/drop/edrop.txt",
            "filename"        :  "spamhaus_edrop.txt",
            }
        }
    
    return dicts[listname].get(key)
```

Comment: Eet verks!  Thanks mucho!  You rule.

Answer (score 0):

You should use eval() to access variables dynamically like that

```
def lookup(listname, key):

    spamhaus_drop = {
        "name"            :  "Spamhaus DROP",
        "URL"             :  "https://www.spamhaus.org/drop/drop.txt",
        "filename"        :  "spamhaus_drop.txt",
    }

    spamhaus_edrop = {
        "name"            :  "Spamhaus EDROP",
        "URL"             :  "https://www.spamhaus.org/drop/edrop.txt",
        "filename"        :  "spamhaus_edrop.txt",
    }

    return eval(listname).get(key)
```

Comment: I thought eval() was no bueno as it's a security risk?

Comment: @DieterichBuxtehude It's only a security risk if the input is dynamically supplied by the user with no filtering.

Comment: But it should still be considered a last resort solution, there are almost always better ones.